# Is there a way to auto turn-on Linux machine?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, scheduling

I know that there are many ways to auto-*shutdown*, but I'm concerned about auto **turn-on**. Is there a command or a small piece of software to turn on the system at given time?

Comment: Automatically booting your PC is a BIOS feature, not an OS feature. What's the make and model of your motherboard?

Answer (score 35):

One alternative is to not shutdown, but to hibernate or suspend the system and then automatically wake it up using `rtcwake` utility.

For example

```
rtcwake -s 3600 -m disk
```

will immediately hibernate (suspend to disk) the system and resume it in 1 hour. Similarly

```
sleep 600; rtcwake -s 60 -m mem
```

will suspend to ram in 10 minutes from now, and then resume after 60 seconds.

You can also wake up the system at given time with `-t` option. It takes seconds since 1970 as an argument, but you can use `date` to convert from human readable format, e.g.

```
rtcwake -m disk -t "$(date -d '2015-02-26 16:12:00' '+%s')"
```

Comment: `rtcwake` can be used to wake the totally shut down PC when it's supported by the BIOS: `rtcwake -m off -t $(date -d '20161111 11:11' +%s)`. Sleeping is not necessary.

Answer (score 19):

Check out the [Wake-on-LAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN) (WoL) feature. [Arch Linux has nice documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wake-on-LAN)  on using it, and do not worry; it is Linux general. In Ubuntu you have the `wakeonlan` package to send magic packets to your machine. Here is [Ubuntu documentation on using WoL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan).

So to turn your machine automatically, you will have to use another machine that will turn it on with WoL.

Comment: Can I install it on ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Wake on Lan only works well if you shut down properly. if you get a power outage or something. WOL will fail. BIOS scheduling will work every time. Look in your BIOS.

Comment: WOL requires another machine to send the packet, so rtcwake is the better solution here. Here's a duplicate question on AskUbuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61708/automatically-sleep-and-wake-up-at-specific-times.

Comment: It does require a second machine but it doesn't have to be a computer. You can send magic packets from an android (and presumably iOS?) phone/tablet.

Comment: @Trengot: yes. You can send Wake-on-LAN messages from iOS device.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, automatic boot is a feature that has to be provided and set up in your BIOS or UEFI and is independent from the OS (like Ubuntu) installed.

Look at the manual of your BIOS/UEFI or mainboard.

Comment: I'm using Dell Inspiron 1545, can it be configured?

Comment: I don't know and I will not do a long research on this, as you are also able to google. Usually yes, unless it is a very old/ancient machine. But you always need a trigger. This can be either a specified time (not available on every machine), a signal from LAN (wake-on-LAN function as described in other answers), switching on the AC power, a keyboard/mouse event, etc... You have to think of how you want to start it and then check whether your BIOS/UEFI/mainboard/device supports this. Google is your friend!

Comment: Actually, I find out that it support wake on lan option in power management in the BIOS menu

Comment: @remassido You may need to enable wake-on-clock in your BIOS, but after that, you should be able to configure an actual wake-up time with a tool like `rtcwake`.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on whether the BIOS/UEFI of your computer supports this feature.

If it does, you can use the Ubuntu package `nvram-wakeup` to set the wakeup date/time.

Read the documentation of the package before using it (`/usr/share/doc/nvram-wakeup/README.mb.gz`) as it is possible that you need to do some work to configure the tool.

Comment: nvram-wakeup's last release was 2010 (v1.1), and many newer motherboards are not supported.